# Intersection point of projective lines

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Whilst stuying geometry, I tried to find the intersection point of two projective lines.

The first projective line $a$ goes through the homogeneous coordinates $[1:0:1]$ and $[1:1:1]$.
The second projective line $b$ goes through the homogeneous coordinates $[1:1:0]$ and $[0:1:0]$.

Now I would like to find their point of intersection. What I tried so far:

$x[1:0:1]+y[1:1:1] = (x+y,y,x+y)$ 
$z[1:1:0]+w[0:1:0] = (z,z+w,0)$

When I solve this system I get: $x=-y=-w$ and $z=0$. 
This would result in the coordinate $(-y,w,0,0)$.

Now I am unsure what to do, or whether this is correct at all. It seems like the intersection point of two projective lines has 4 coordinates now? That doesn't make sense to me. Could someone maybe help me with this problem?

Comment: @jjagmath Ah I see, there was a typo, sorry. I editted it quickly. Would the "calculation" now be correct? thank you for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the right thing in solving the system of equations, but what you need to do now is substitute back in the point you are looking for:

$$[x+y:y:x+y] = [-y+y:y:-y+y] = [0:y:0] = [0:1:0]$$

or equivalently

$$[z:z+w:0] = [0:w:0]=[0:1:0]$$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't substitute the values back in, that's where it went wrong.